# Stop Android OS auto-update

Tags: android, auto-update, android-2.2-froyo

We have a variety of devices for testing purposes, and now that Froyo is being pushed (to the Nexus One so far at least), we have to constantly dismiss upgrade requests.  There is no apparent "stop asking me" button.

So, is there any way I can disable OTA OS updates?  We want a number of these phones to stay on old OS versions.

Comment: You can cut it off from internet connections, but other than that I don't know of a way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove SystemUpdater.apk from /system/app. From terminal (with ADB)

```
adb pull /system/app/SystemUpdater.apk C:/Path/to/your/desktop //Backup the file (just in case)  
adb remount                                       //Remount the system partition to read-write  
adb shell rm /system/app/SystemUpdater.apk              //Remove the apk
```

Warning - this will permanently disable system updates, until you push SystemUpdater back to /system/app

Comment: Do I need to root the device to use this?  If there's an alternative, I would prefer to keep these devices as close to factory spec as possible.

Comment: At best, that can only work with rooted devices, as `/system/app` is not readable, let alone writable, on standard production devices, AFAIK.

Comment: CommonsWare is correct, to use this, you do need a modified boot.img (which means root), but you don't necessarily need to have a modified ROM. For a nexus one, you should be able to root and install a custom boot image but leave the stock ROM on the phone.

Comment: Cool, well not my ideal solution, but a good answer none the less.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For XOOM running android 3 honeycomb. You have to remove **Upgrader.apk** (not SystemUpdater).

```
adb pull /system/app/Upgrader.apk C:/Path/to/your/desktop //Backup the file (just in case)  
adb remount                                       //Remount the system partition to read-write  
adb shell rm /system/app/Upgrader.apk              //Remove the apk
```

Answer (score 2):

From ADB with root access:

```
adb shell pm disable com.google.android.systemupdater
```

Not need delete apk.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very old Lenovo Yoga 2 1050F tablet, Android 5.0.1(Lollipop). Today year 2020 it made an unexpected OTA firmware download. After downloading a file reboot gives a signature error which may relate to my root and half broken recovery boot app. This is how I disabled a system update
`adb devices | adb shell | su | pm disable com.lenovo.ota`